# Mapping of Google Cloud VMs to physical machines

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am using Google Cloud to run a few experiments. Now, when I create a VM instance of say 4 VCPUs, what is the mapping of those 4 VCPUs to the actual physical machine? Also, what does 4 VCPUs actually entail? Am I getting a machine that has say, 4 processors? Or do I get 4 nodes on a machine that has say, 8 processors? If the latter is the case, doesn't the utilization of the remaining 4 nodes affect the performance of my job?

In the Google Cloud documentation, they say that `For the n1 series of machine types, a virtual CPU is implemented as a single hardware hyper-thread.` The thing is, I'm not exactly sure what a single hardware hyper-thread means. An interesting fact is that I did `cat /proc/cpuinfo` on an 8 VCPU instance that I had reserved, and it had a field called `cpu cores` whose value was 4. Again, what does that indicate?

I would like to understand the underlying hardware below the VM instances as it would help me in optimizing jobs that have multithreading enabled.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When we run `cat /proc/cpuinfo`, which shows 8, it means that the system has access to 8 threads (as in your example) and `cpu cores` is 4 because that is the number of physical cores.

About your question of "optimizing jobs that have multithreading enabled",  the only difference is that you're accessing the vCPUs through a hypervisor rather than directly as hyper-threads on an Intel processor. In fact, multi-threading strategies for applications shouldn't really be any different just because of the hypervisor layer.

You can also read the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/bJF4Z5kjNig) which is about the relations among virtual CPU, hyper-thread, and physical core.